# Flex-direction column makes flex items overlap IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm running into an issue using flexbox in IE11. When using `flex-direction: column` the flex-items overlap:

[image]

In other browsers (chrome, safari) it looks like this:

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    World
  </div>
</div>
```

I've made a codepen to demonstrate the issue:

http://codepen.io/csteur/pen/XMgpad

What am I missing to make this layout not overlap in IE11?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is caused by the 0% in your `.flex` class. Change it to auto then it should not be a problem:

```
.flex {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Instead of `flex: 1 1 0%;` use `flex: 1 1 auto;`

```css
.container {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    World
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

My particular solution to this issue was that I needed to explicitly set the width on the containing element. Since `flex` is set to `column` IE11 will automatically expand the width of the container to accommodate the content of the children (remember that the flex boxes are flipped on their sides in `column` alignment so when they overflow they grow horizontally instead of vertically).

So my code would look like:

```
.container {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%; // needs explicit width
}

.flex {
  flex: 1 1 auto; // or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note also that `flex: 1;` compiles to `flex : 1 1 0%;`, so it's better (for IE users) if you explicitly write `flex: 1 1 auto;`, as mentioned above.